# How can I change the size of an array?

Tags: .net, arrays

I have a defined array:

```
    Private shapePoints(picWidth, picHeight) As Integer
```

I need to rechange size of this array in code.

How can I do it?

Comment: See the [Redim statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2(v=vs.100).aspx) in MSDN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ReDim shapePoints(picWidth, picHeight)
```